# MVC Web API 2 - Using custom attribute on action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute

I am attempting to create a custom ActionFilterAttribute as shown.  The attribute will only contain a property of Path.

```
public class TestLinkAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Path { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}
```

I would like to be able to access this attribute on the help pages area that web api integrates similar to this.

```
<td class="api-testLink">
@{ 
var attrColl = api.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<TestLinkAttribute>();
      if(attrColl.Count > 0)
      {
          <p>@attrColl[0].Path</p>
      }
}
</td>
```

I decorated the action like this.

```
 [TestLink(Path = "api/surveys/72469282/responses")]
 public string GetQuestions(int id)
 {
 }
```

This is completely new territory to me and i have done a bit of research but can't / don't know if there is a quick way to accomplish this.  Currently the output is empty as the attribute collection is never > 0

Comment: I've built a simple version of this, creating a custom attribute, assigning it to an Action and then pulling the attribute out to display a `Path` property like you've shown. It all works in my sample solution. Are you able to provide an example that does not work and host it on e.g. Github?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't at the moment. It's an internal app and the company is very strict about hosting this type of thing externally.

Comment: Is there any chance something else is necessary because I am trying to access the attribute within the help area of this application and something with reflection? I can do this no problem outside of that area.

Comment: I can't think of anything else. Chances are the problem is in something that's not detailed in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After further research, you must inherit from System.Web.Http.Filters when you create the custom attribute with a controller inheriting from ApiController.  I was inheriting from the standard mvc ActionFilterAttribute from MVC namespace (System.Web.MVC).

```
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace App.Extensions
{
    public class TestLinkAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now when i access the attribute from the ApiGroup.cshtml in the HelpPage area, i can use the following it it will properly obtain the value.

```
var attrColl = api.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<TestLinkAttribute>();
```